# Copy underlying c++ object in R when exposing the class with Rcpp modules

Tags: c++, rcpp

I am exposing a c++ class to R using Rcpp modules. Once exposed to R, I can call exposed member functions etc. I am struggling, however, when I try to copy the underlying c++ object. Is there an easy way to do so?

Lets say I have exposed a c++ class called "Foo" using Rcpp modules. In c++ the code looks the following way:

```
class Foo{
   public:
   double a;
   Foo(double _a):a(_a){}
}
```

In R, I instantiate an instance of that class the following way:

```
cl <- new("class", 2)
```

The variable `cl` contains a pointer pointing to the c++ object. Thus, when I do

```
dl <- cl
dl$a <- 3
```

It will also change the output of `cl$a` since I only copied the pointer not the object it is pointing to. How do I copy the object the pointer is pointing to?

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit: _"copy the underlying c++ object"_ could mean a variety of things.  Explain what you expected, show what you got, ideally with reproducible code.  As it stands, the question is unanswerable.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think you will need to write yourself a "deep copy" helper function which, say, calls `new()` and the copies the of the `Foo` object over.